# Does this group have an element of order $4$ or infinite order?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Define the homomorphism $M:\mathbb{Z}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^3$ as
$$M(a,b,c)=(2a+4b-2c, 2a+6b-2c, 2a+4b+c)$$

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}^3/M(\mathbb{Z}^3)$.

(1). Does $G$ have an element of order $4$?

(2). Does $G$ have an element of infinite order?

Any ideas?

For the first part, I started with an arbitrary element $(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{Z}^3$.If $M(\mathbb{Z}^3)+(a,b,c)$ has order $4$, we get the following system of linear equations:
$$2x+4y-2z=4a$$ $$2x+6y-2z=4b$$ $$2x+4y+z=4c$$
in the variables $x,y,z$ where $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}$. Since $M(\mathbb{Z}^3)+(a,b,c)$ has order $4$, the trick is to make sure that $(4a,4b,4c)\in M(\mathbb{Z}^3)$ but $(ka,kb,kc)\notin M(\mathbb{Z}^3)$ for $k<4$.

For second part, I don't have any idea.

Is there any clever way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that solving $M(a,b,c) = [x,y,z]$, we get 
$$ \eqalign{  a &= \frac{7}{6} x - y + \frac{z}{3}\cr
              b &= -\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}\cr
              c &= - \frac{x}{3} + \frac{z}{3}\cr} $$
In particular, $6 \mathbb Z^3 \subset M(\mathbb Z^3)$.

Do you see how that answers both parts of the question?

Comment: Related to to Robert's answer, I also suggest you draw a picture of $M(\mathbb Z^3)$ as a subset of $\mathbb Z^3$, and construct a natural system of representatives for the cosets of $G$. It will be a nice geometric picture.